# Scala-Spark: sample with replacement, specify probabilities

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to do sampling with replacement in Scala/Spark, defining the probabilities for each class.

This is how I would do it in R.

```
# Vector to sample from
x <- c("User1","User2","User3","User4","User5")

# Occurenciens from which to obtain sampling probabilities
y <- c(2,4,4,3,2)

# Calculate sampling probabilities
p <- y / sum(y)

# Draw sample with replacement of size 10
s <- sample(x, 10, replace = TRUE, prom = p)

# Which yields (for example):
[1] "User5" "User1" "User1" "User5" "User2" "User4" "User4" "User2" "User1" "User3"
```

How can I do the same in Scala / Spark?

Comment: Please review the docs before asking on SO.

Comment: I have been searching the documentation extensively but I haven't been able to find an answer. I would be grateful if you could point me to that, or, alternatively, if you could point me to guidance on how to use the documentation more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into it some more and as I was saying before, I don't think the stratified sampling stuff is applicable, so here's another idea.

With sampling weights `p(i)` (nonnegative and adding up to 1), the number of samples for each datum `x(i)` has a binomial distribution, which can be approximated by a Poisson distribution if none of the weights are too big. The Poisson parameter will be `p(i)*n` where `n` is the total number of samples to draw.

Iterate over the data, generating `m` copies of it (possibly zero) where `m` is Poisson-distributed with parameter `p(i)*n`. Flatten all the copies into a list. Ta-da, that's all.

The length of the result is random, with expected value `n`. If it's too short, I guess you could generate more, or throw away some if it's too long. Presumably if you're careful, you would have to take the weights into account when you fix up the list that way.

To generate Poisson values, you can use `PoissonDistribution.sample` from apache-commons-math3 (as Spark MLlib itself does), or, if you're brave, you could implement it yourself.

Good luck and have fun. If you have further questions, I can try to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the page for [MLLib Basic Statistics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html) under the heading [Stratified sampling](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html#stratified-sampling). I think maybe `sampleByKey` or `sampleByKeyExact` might be appropriate here.

Comment: I have looked at that but this is not what I'm looking for I think. I'll revisit it however.

Comment: I don't understand how it is different. Maybe you can explain.

Comment: I think you're probably right. I'll need to try. Would you have a worked example of that? I'm a newbie in scala and can't really work out the syntax. Specifically, i need to calculate the fractions from a column in a dataframe.

Comment: I think you're right, those functions aren't applicable. I tried to figure out a way to restate your problem so that those functions would work, but I didn't find anything. I'll think about another way to go about it.